# Trigger to match a field in object a (Contact) with another object b (Ponto__c) and populate a relationship lookup (Contato__c)

Tags: trigger, lookup, update

I need developer a Trigger to match a field in object a (Contact) with another object b (Ponto__c) and populate a relationship lookup (Contato__c).

Details

1- I have a custom object **`Ponto__c`** related to the standard object **`Contact`** via lookup field **`Contato__c`**.

I need to check if **`Contact.Inscricao_Numero__c`** = **`Ponto__c.Inscricao_Numero__c`** and update the lookup field **`Ponto__c.Contato__c`** in object **`Ponto__c`**.

I Tried this, but i am a little lost.

```
Trigger updateContatoPonto6 on Ponto__c (after insert, after update) {

// build a set of receivable Inscricao_Numero__c
Set <Decimal> receberInscricaoNumero = new Set <Decimal> ();

for(Ponto__c pontos : trigger.New)
{
    receberInscricaoNumero.add(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c);
}

// Map the contacts Inscricao_Numero__c and the actual contacts records based on the receivable Inscricao_Numero__c
Map <Decimal, Contact> matchingcontactsMap = new Map <Decimal, Contact> ();

for (Contact contacts : [Select Id, Inscricao_Numero__c From Contact Where Inscricao_Numero__c IN :receberInscricaoNumero])
{
    matchingcontactsMap.put(contacts.Inscricao_Numero__c, contacts);
}

List <Ponto__c> receivablesToUpdate = new List <Ponto__c> ();

// go through the records in the trigger again and check whether we have found a matching receivable and inscricao_numero__c
for(Ponto__c pontos : trigger.New)
{
    if (matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c) == null)
    {
        // we found a mathing one
        pontos.inscricao_Numero__c = matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c).Inscricao_Numero__c;

        // add it to a separate list and update it
        receivablesToUpdate.add(pontos);
    }
} 
update receivablesToUpdate;
}
```

I hope have been clear, the trigger runs, but i cant update lookup field Ponto__c.Contact__C

Please someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  I would start by changing the trigger from an after trigger to a before trigger since you're modifying the same records you're inserting/updating.  Then there'll be no need for an explicit "update" call.

Then this line

```
if (matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c) == null)
```

is wrong because you want it to match if the key can be found in the map, i.e. your condition is non-null.

And in order to populate the `Contact` on the `Ponto__c`, you just need to do:

```
if (matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c) != null)
{
   // we found a matching one
   pontos.Contato__c = matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c).Id;
}
```

since it's the Contact's Id you want to assign.

Comment: Hi George S., tks for your attention, I think I was not clear enough,

I have an excel file, I will import the excel file the records of **`Ponto__c `**, the only relationship of this worksheet is a **`Ponto__c.inscricao_numero__c`** column. At the time importing files will be manually.

I need to validate that **`Contact.Inscricao_Numero__c`** = **`Ponto__c.Inscricao_Numero__c`**
**`if = true`**, then update the lookup **`Ponto__c.Contato__c`** field with the **`Contact Id`**, to create the relationship between Contact and the records of Ponto__c.

Comment: That use case should be covered by my answer.  The trigger will fire when you import your Pontos, and populate the matching Contacts.  If this is not what you want, could you be more specific about the problem you are having?

Comment: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger updateContatoPonto6 caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: updateContatoPonto6: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.updateContatoPonto6: line 23, column 1

23:       pontos.Contato__c = matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c).Id;

I need this update: Ponto__c.Contato__c =  Contact.Id,,, if have the same inscricao_numero__c between Contact and Ponto__c,

ok?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you should change the trigger to "before insert, before update" and remove the explicit update.

Comment: i.e.,,, if you create a object named Pontos__c and create 2 fields, contato__c lookup field object Contact and another field Inscricao_numero__c, and create in object Contact inscricao_numero__c,  you can simulate this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, not yet, i will change ... before insert, before update

Comment: Hello Friend! this worked,,, I will do some testing,,,
I have to IMPORT 80000 records ...
Thank you for your patience ...

I will study more this trigger, I have to also link some also profiles ...

Comment: Make sure you understand why it works.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm is a good source of reference.  And I would want to write some good unit tests to test my trigger.

Comment: Just a question,

How can I do? If I do not find the inscricao_numero__c? how do I do to clean up the old relationship pontos__c.contato__c field?

Comment: You add an else to your if statement and set pontos.Contato__c = null.  So if it's not in the map, it will be "cleaned".

Comment: Hi @George S., i need your help again, the trigger works fine in an org dev, but i cant make deploy, code coverage Failure Coverage of the organization's code is 0%. Would you please suggest me what I gotta do?